# Libre office Writer: image linking latex-like

Tags: latex, libreoffice

As with latex, is it possible to write the path to an image and then get its content automatically updated by the program? I would need something like this tool without changing editor.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, LibreOffice Writer works differently from LateX, but there is a handy feature to link graphics to a document instead of embedding them. When the graphics change, the document content also changes (provided that the changed graphic uses the same filename as the one before; but that's the same in LateX.

How to do it:
Choose "Insert" -> "Graphics" -> "From File"  and check "Link". That's all.

P.S. You can also ex-post embed all linked images via "Edit" -> "Links" -> "Break Links". This makes it much simpler to send the document to reviewers or other people.